# Redundant Keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, key

Currently working on a MySQL database which has key declarations such as

```
KEY 'id' (id),
KEY 'username' (username),
KEY 'user_id' (username, id)
```

Does this affect how our data works in anyway? Would eliminating this improve our database's efficiency? I concluded they were redundant but I am curious if the person who came before me created these for any reason.

Comment: There is only 1 redundant key in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good write up about this in [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/utils-task-find-extra-indexes.html):

> MySQL allows its users to create several indexes that might be the
>   same (duplicate indexes) or partially similar (redundant indexes) in
>   its structure. Although duplicate indexes have no advantages, there
>   are some cases where redundant indexes might be helpful. However, both
>   have disadvantages. **Duplicate and redundant indexes slow down update
>   and insert operations. As a result it is usually a good idea to find
>   and remove them.**

Answer (score 0):

I always eliminate redundant indexes and I notice increase in writing speed without any effect in querying speed.

I can think of situations where having a redundant index *might* increase reading speed, but it is unlikely and the increase will be minimal.

In conclusion, I warmly recommend removing the redundant indexes: it will increase writing speed.